# enabling multiprocess for pandas data frame multiplication

Tags: python, pandas

in my application, i need to perform multiplication of a very large data frame with a large

```
full_allocation_multiidx_pd.shape
(32892090, 10)
weights_and_time_series.shape
(30839760,)
```

by doing

```
full_allocation_multiidx_pd.multiply(weights_and_time_series,axis=0)
```

I realize pandas multiplication only used 1 core of my 16 cores. I think if it becomes a MPI process it would be much faster. Are there any pandas way to enable multiprocess? Or do I have to hard code something myself? Thank you.

Comment: Check out dask.

Comment: `multiprocessing` check the package